# How to cancel a custom operator-pending command

Tags: map-operator

I want to make a custom search, accessible with operator-pending commands;
I use `onoremap` to make it work in this mode.

It's working well, and I can use my command (let's say it's mapped to `zz`) with `czz`, `yzz`...

But when the function called by the mapping does not match anything, I would like to make it react exactly like when I type the following normal mode command:

```
c/never\&match<cr>
```

> E486: Pattern not found: never\&match

An error is gently displayed, and *it goes back to normal mode*, because an error happened.

For now, when my custom search fails with the example `czz` command, it enters into insert mode, as if the search was successful. That's my problem:

**How can I cancel the `czz` command and go back to normal mode, when the search inside the `zz` mapping fails?**

To solve it I tried to put the following in the right place, but in vain: `exe "normal! \<esc>"`

Here is an example code:

```
" Create the o-mapping:
onoremap zz :<c-u>call MyQTest()<cr>

function! MyQTest()
    " Just below, performs a custom search that will set two 
    " vars, 'l:start' and 'l:end', the bounds of the area to
    " work with:

    " [ ... ]

    " Finally we get some values, for example:
    " let l:start = 5
    " let l:end = 10

    " But if the search fails, instead of the two lines above,
    " the values could be:
    let l:start = -1
    let l:end = -1

    if l:start == -1 || l:end == -1
        " HERE is the problem:
        " If the search fails, how can I completely cancel the operator-pending 
        " command and return to normal mode, instead of start editing (with
        " the 'c' normal command) ?
        return
    endif

    " Make a selection, for operator-pending mode:
    call cursor(0, l:start)
    normal v
    call cursor(0, l:end)
endf
```

Comment: You could throw an error or add an `echoerr`. But it won't be as "nice" as your `c/...` example, because it will lead to two error messages and so will require a `press enter to continue`.

Comment: Try `return feedkeys("\e")` that seems to work from my little test here.

Answer (score 1):

It works by using:

```
call feedkeys("\e")
```

even if an error message is hard to display in all the cases.